# gnu.trove classes throws java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero

Tags: java, trove4j

My application uses gnu.trove version 2.0.3. Recently it is throwing divide by zero exceptions in different areas of the gnu.trove library code

e.g.:
1.

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
at gnu.trove.TIntHash.index(TIntHash.java:201)
at gnu.trove.TIntObjectHashMap.get(TIntObjectHashMap.java:204)
```

2.

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
at gnu.trove.TIntHash.insertionIndex(TIntHash.
at gnu.trove.TIntObjectHashMap.put(TIntObjectHashMap.java:153)
```

3.

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
at gnu.trove.TPrimitiveHash.capacity(TPrimitiveHash.java:99)
at gnu.trove.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:358)
at gnu.trove.TIntLongHashMap.put(TIntLongHashMap.java:165)
```

This is the snippet of the application code that throws divide by zero exceptions in one scenario:

```
TIntLongHashMap testMap = new TIntLongHashMap();
TIntLongHashMap test1Map = new TIntLongHashMap();
.
.
.
TIntLongIterator iter = test1Map.iterator();
for (int i = test1Map.size(); i-- > 0; )
{
        iter.advance();
        **testMap.put(iter.key(), iter.value());**
}
```

From the stack trace, I looked at the lines of code that are throwing these exceptions inside these library classes:
1.
**at gnu.trove.TIntHash.index(TIntHash.java:201)**

```
protected int index(int val)
/ / {
/ 185 / byte[] states = _states;
/ 186 / int[] set = _set;
/ 187 / int length = states.length;
/ 188 / int hash = _hashingStrategy.computeHashCode(val) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
/ 189 / int index = hash % length;
/ /
/ 191 / if ((states[index] != 0) && ((states[index] == 2) || (set[index] != val)))
/ / {
/ /
/ 194 / int probe = 1 + hash % (length - 2);
/ / do
/ / {
/ 197 / index -= probe;
/ 198 / if (index < 0) {
/ 199 / index += length;
/ / }
**/ 201 / } while ((states[index] != 0) && ((states[index] == 2) || (set[index] != val)))**;
/ / }
/ /
/ /
/ 205 / return states[index] == 0 ? -1 : index;
/ / }
```

2.
**at gnu.trove.TIntHash.insertionIndex(TIntHash.
java:271**)

```
protected int insertionIndex(int val)
/ / {
byte[] states = _states;
/ 220 / int[] set = _set;
/ 221 / int length = states.length;
/ 222 / int hash = _hashingStrategy.computeHashCode(val) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
/ 223 / int index = hash % length;
/ /
/ 225 / if (states[index] == 0)
/ 226 / return index;
/ 227 / if ((states[index] == 1) && (set[index] == val)) {
/ 228 / return -index - 1;
/ / }
/ /
/ 231 / int probe = 1 + hash % (length - 2);
/ 245 / if (states[index] != 2)
/ / {
/ / do
/ / {
/ 249 / index -= probe;
/ 250 / if (index < 0) {
/ 251 / index += length;
/ / }
/ 253 / } while ((states[index] == 1) && (set[index] != val));
/ / }
/ /
/ /
/ /
/ /
/ 259 / if (states[index] == 2) {
/ 260 / int firstRemoved = index;
/ 261 / while ((states[index] != 0) && ((states[index] == 2) || (set[index] != val)))
/ / {
/ 263 / index -= probe;
/ 264 / if (index < 0) {
/ 265 / index += length;
/ / }
/ / }
/ 268 / return states[index] == 1 ? -index - 1 : firstRemoved;
/ / }
/ /
/ **271 / return states[index] == 1 ? -index - 1 : index;
/ / }**
```

3.
at gnu.trove.TPrimitiveHash.capacity(TPrimitiveHash.java:99)

```
/ / protected int capacity()
/ / {
**/ 99 / return _states.length;**
/ / }
```

As you see, these lines do not do any division.

So why are these divide by zero exceptions being thrown? What are the scenarios within the gnu.trove classes that can thrown these java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero exceptions in the code?

Comment: you don't consider this a division: int probe = 1 + hash % (length - 2); ??

Comment: Did you make any changes to [`hashCode()`](http://www.baeldung.com/java-hashcode) logic of any of your classes?

Comment: @Stultuske int probe = 1 + hash % (length - 2); is line 231 whereas exception is thrown at line 271 for TIntHash. java

Comment: @PM 77-1 No changes were made to the hashCode() logic but multiple threads access this code simultaneously. Can that cause divide by zero exception during the calculation of the hashCode?

Comment: Another wild question: Are you absolutely sure that you are looking at the right version of source for *trove*?

Comment: @user6060190 well, duh. but seeing as none of those lines can possibly throw that Exception, it is possible that you've altered the code after, and are running a previous version.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Yes .. trove-2.0.3.jar

Comment: @Stultuske Isn't it possible that when there are lot of processes / threads accessing the _states array, at one point in time, the _states.length value must be returning 0 which causes divide-by-zero error while calculating the _states index or probe?

Comment: @user6060190 sure. at which point, your stacktrace would point to the very line in which the division was done. Does it?

Comment: Can the division operation in one of the constructors of these classes throw the exception?

Comment: Trove library has many bugs and effectively unsupported, you should better switch to [fastutil](https://github.com/vigna/fastutil), which is supported

Comment: Have you used Proguard (or something similar)? In general I'd say there's probably a concurrency issue, but the line number mismatches indicate a classpath problem (multiple versions of the code). I haven't been able to find a release which would match the error you're seeing.

Comment: @Rob Eden I have not used Progaurd or anything similar.